# get route id in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**Order ID** 
example i have order id = 51 
 like in this route =>
/admin/order/51

how to call the order id from routes to **Helpers.PHP**

this my **Helpers.PHP**

```
public static function getAllProductFromOrderItem($user_id = '', $order_id = '') {
if (Auth::check()) {
            if ($user_id == "") $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

            return OrderItem::with('product')->where('user_id', $user_id)->where('order_id', $order_id)->get();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**Web.PHP**

```
Route::get('/order/show/{id}', "HomeController@orderShow",)->name('user.order.show');
```

Comment: you should be able to access it using `request()->route('required_key')`, where required key is the key you are defining in the route.

Comment: $order_id = request()->route('id'); <---- like this one?

Comment: Yes, correct! @Mr Lara

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like the following closure in your route:

```
Route::get('/admin/order/{id}', function ($id) {
    return HelperClass::getAllProductFromOrderItem('', $id);
});
```

It might give you the idea of how you can access your helper functions from the route files.

Comment: not work my route on **web.PHP**   
`Route::get('/order/show/{id}', "HomeController@orderShow",)->name('user.order.show');`